# How can I add 1 for my voting system in access database my SQL is wrong

Tags: sql, vb.net

How can I add 1 for my voting system in access database.

Current code below:

```
Dim sql as string = "UPDATE president SET votes = '" &1& "' WHERE Student = '"&listbox1.text&"'"
```

Comment: can you help me with my sql statement?  It's my first time using it

Comment: votes = votes+1

Comment: Dim sql as string = "UPDATE president SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Student = '"&listbox1.text&"'"

Comment: Like that?? Im using visual basic btw

Answer (score 3):

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed.

**Always use parameters** to make sql string easier to write and avoid Sql injection.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update president SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE Student = @Student;")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Student", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ListBox1.Text
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @jpdelos-santoshortelano the most important sentence in this entire answer is "Always use parameters". http://bobby-tables.com cannot stress this strongly enough